# If else datetime python function

Tags: python

In my data I have a column called expiration date where some of the events have an expiration date and some don't so when I load the date that column looks like the following loaded as an object:

```
expiration_date
2017-06-14
2018-01-15
9999-12-31
```

I then convert it to datetime with errors coerced through which will leave the 9999-12-31 dates as NaT

```
data.expiration_date = pd.to_datetime(data.expiration_date, errors = 'coerce')
```

I'd then like to create a function that creates a new column binary column that if the expiration date is NaT then it is a 1 otherwise it is a 0.  I tried the following:

```
def status(data):
    if data[data.expiration_date.isnull()]:
       return 1
    else:
       return 0

data['event'] = data.apply(status, axis = 1)
```

but I get the following error message which I figure is trying to use isnull on a column in datetime format.  I haven't been able to find a good way to solve for null values in datetime.

```
"'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'isnull'", 'occurred at index 0'
```

Any thoughts, I'm new to python and any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: `if data[data.expiration_date.isnull()]` makes zero sense. You might want something like `if data.expiration_date is None` which can also be written as `if not data.expiration_date`.

Comment: I tried running that code but everything was assigned a 0 whether there was a valid datetime or if it was NaT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one out with lambda checking type of the data

Example dataframe

```
mydict1 = {'expiration_date' : ['2017-06-14','2018-01-15','9999-12-31']}
df=pd.DataFrame(mydict1)
df.expiration_date=pd.to_datetime(df.expiration_date, errors = 'coerce')
print(df)
```

Output

```
       expiration_date
    0   2017-06-14
    1   2018-01-15
    2   NaT
```

Keeping the date part alone

```
df.expiration_date.values.astype('M8[D]')
print(df)
```

Apply function on series

```
def status(data):

    if (type(data)!=datetime.date):
        return 1
    return 0

df['event']=df.expiration_date.dt.date.apply(status)
print(df)
```

Output

```
expiration_date event
0   2017-06-14  0
1   2018-01-15  0
2   NaT         1
```

A Shorter solution without lambda

```
df['event']=df['expiration_date'].isnull().astype('int')
```

Output

```
expiration_date event
0   2017-06-14  0
1   2018-01-15  0
2   NaT         1
```

Just playing around another similar solution to above

```
df['event']=0
df.loc[df.expiration_date.isnull(),'event']=1
```

Comment: This is perfect df['event']=df['expiration_date'].isnull().astype('int').  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`isnull` is a method of `DataFrame`, so you don't need that apply.

I think what you want is:

```
data.expiration_date.isnull().astype(int)
```